# find a date between two dates in T SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have two DateTime columns in my table, ArrivalDateTime,DepartureDateTime with values like '26/11/2012 00:00:00' '28/11/2012 00:00:00' Now I want to find all the records from this table where a given date say 27/11/2012 exist between those dates using T Sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`BETWEEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE '2012-11-27' BETWEEN ArrivalDateTime AND DepartureDateTime
```

Comment: regard, that between also returns true, if date = ArrivalDateTime or date = DepartureDateTime

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @GivenDate VARCHAR(10)
SET @GivenDate = '27/11/2012'

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, ArrivalDateTime, 103) < CONVERT(DATETIME, @GivenDate, 103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, DepartureDateTime, 103) > CONVERT(DATETIME, @GivenDate, 103)
```

If you want to include the arrival & departure dates.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, ArrivalDateTime, 103) <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @GivenDate, 103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, DepartureDateTime, 103) >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @GivenDate, 103)
```

If you want to compare only dates & not time then try this.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ArrivalDateTime, 103) <= CONVERT(DATE, @GivenDate, 103) AND CONVERT(DATE, DepartureDateTime, 103) >= CONVERT(DATE, @GivenDate, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
select * from MYTABLE where ArrivalDateTime < '2012-11-27' and DepartureDateTime > '2012-11-27'
```